# Linear speed from conservation of angular momentum and energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

A massless spring with constant $k$ is mounted on a turntable of rotational inertia $I$, as shown in the figure. The turntable is on a frictionless vertical axle, though initially it's not rotating. The spring is compressed a distance $x$ from its equilibrium, with a mass m placed against it. When the spring is released, the mass moves at right angles to a line through the turntable's center, and slides without friction across the table and over the edge. Find expressions for the linear speed of the mass and the rotational speed of the turntable.

I understand that the rotational speed can be found from the conservation of energy if I get the linear speed, which I am having difficulty solving.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the linear speed of the mass from the conservation of mechanical energy *and* angular momentum: for the mass, $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}=mbv\,\hat{z}$ (where $\hat{z}$ is normal to the turntable and points upwards, use the right hand rule), and for the turntable $\vec{L}=I\vec{\omega}=-I\omega\,\hat{z}$, so
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2\\
mbv=I\omega
\end{cases}
$$
which gives expressions both for $\omega$ and $v$.